# How to update a Static array in vb.net

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am converting VBA6 code to VB.net in Visual Studio 2105.  My VBA6 code loads an array with lines from a file and retains it for repeated use like this:

```
Static sArr as Variant
'Load the file to a String called S  (details omitted for brevity here)
sArr = split(S, vbNewline)
```

This works fine; I have one line in each entry in sArr, as required and I can get any line from the array whenever it is required.

In VB.Net (when using Visual Studio) I have converted this to the following:

```
Static sArr() as String
'Load the file to a String called S (details omitted for brevity here)
sArr = S.Split(vbNewLine)
```

This fails with an error saying `"Error BC30451: 'sArr' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."`.  At one level, this error message is clearly wrong.  sArr is definitely being declared.  It is declared at the start of the routine in which the Error is declared by the compiler and by watch.  However, it is declared as Static and this seems to cause the problem.

I have tried the above approach but with this non-static Dim statement 
`Dim sArr() As String`
and it works fine in VB.Net.  The required line by line array is generated.

How can I get this to work in VB.Net a way that allows me to retain the data in a Static array?  In VB.Net assigning a Static Object or Array = to the (non Static) sArr or directly to the S.Split itself simply does not work.  It seems the the problem is something to do with the information being Static, but how does one fix this?

Comment: the error message would indicate that `sArr` is declared elsewhere than where you are trying to use it.  The post gives no context, but seems like an issue of scope.

Answer (score 0):

While omitting unnecessary content is admirable, it seems that you are omitting content required for context.  I would suggest two things. One, switch to generics and use a list of strings, and two, take everthing that you excluded for brevity and turn it into a function that returns a single string.  This will make testing and debugging easier.

You seem to be implying that Static doesn't work in vs 2015, and the compiler is throwing an error on valud code.  While the compiler obviously has bugs, it just as obviously mainly works. Static works.

Here is a link to a .net fiddle that basically does what you say you want to do: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3DXFJs.  I've added writelines to illustrate the program flow, and that the variable is only set once, but otherwise it does as you say -- populates a `Static` list of strings, using both a list and an array.  Note that I use two different functions, both using a static variable sArr, and they both get set once, and only once in their respective functions.

Comment: [jmoreno](http://stackoverflow.com/users/234954/jmoreno) indeed, I expected that and find that the issue is not with Static.  The Watch window gives the message quoted above even when there is data in the Static sArr().  So, if there is a bug, it is in Watch.  I'm now experimenting with List instead of an Array in attempt to get this to work.  It is nearly working but I'm still not quite there, though learning that there really is a lot to change when migrating from VBA6 to VB.net.  Heck!

Comment: hmn, if you are seeing that in the watch window, I would expect that you have it at the wrong scope--static variables can only be seen inside the method they are declared in.  in the watch window, variables get the currently executing scope when declared.

Comment: The declaration, use of Static and the errors all occur within one routine (I've now revised the main question to state this).  That was why I was able to simplify the initial question; there is only one routine involved.  I understand that to be the very simplest implementation.